# Does there exist some relations between Cryptography and Algebraic Topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, cryptography, applications

We  know that there are many application of Cryptography in our real life.
 Are there any relation between Cryptography and Algebraic Topology?
If yes, please suggest me some link or books.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the "huge" applications of algebraic topology that "we" know?

Comment: I think, one would need a very long cable to connect both. What is clear is that one cannot help desiging a cryptographic scheme via using algebraic topology. On the other hand, a new cryptographic algorithm deseigned cannot help to solve algebraic topology related questions.

Comment: This is quite vague. Presumably though you can go Algebraic Topology -> Algebraic Geometry or Number Theory (elliptic cohomology fits under both AG and NT) -> Cryptography.

Answer (score 4):

Braid-based cryptography uses braid groups to produce cryptographic schemes starting with the Anshel–Anshel–Goldfeld key exchange at around year 2000. Braid groups arise as the fundamental groups of topological spaces called the configuration spaces, and they also arise as the mapping class groups of punctured disks. However, braid-based cryptographic schemes are now thought to be insecure even though they originally looked very promising.

See [Patrick Dehornoy's survey paper](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~dehornoy/Surveys/Dgw.pdf) or [David Garber's survey paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.3941.pdf) for more information on Braids based cryptography.